# Is there a simple way to find out if a boost::adjacency_list is empty?

Tags: c++, boost, adjacency-list, printer-control-language

I'm using a LCCP from the Point Cloud Library, but I'm quite that I'm doing something wrong.
I think I narrowed the Error down and it has something to do with the `SuperVoxelAdjacencyList sv_adjacency_list; 
lccp.getSVAdjacencyList (sv_adjacency_list);`

because I've implemented a other way to get the adjacency. The documentation states that

> [out] adjacency_list_arg  The supervoxel adjacency list with classified
>   (convex/concave) edges. On error the list is empty.

So now I'm wondering if there is a way find out if the list is emtpy.
Every help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say if `boost::num_vertices(sv_adjacency_list) == 0` you can conclude it's empty.

Of course, you could look at the number of edges instead.

See also: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/graph/doc/graph_concepts.html